# Can I use the Ubuntu Nexus 7 Desktop Installer on other tablets?

Tags: tablet, ubuntu-touch

could I install Ubuntu on galaxy note using Nexus 7 Desktop Installer?

Answer (score 4):

No, the installer only supports the 8GB and 16GB Nexus 7 devices.

The key aspect to running Ubuntu on tablet hardware is whether there exists an accelerated Xorg driver for that hardware available for Ubuntu. Many SoC vendors do not provide such a driver, since it is a significant amount of work, and they are already supporting the Android graphics stack (SurfaceFlinger).

Without this driver, it is unlikely for Ubuntu to run well (or at all) on the device.

I led the team that wrote this installer and created the image, so that's my source of information for you. :)

Thanks.

Comment: You are probably right, but do you have any sort of sources for your statement? Or perhaps some reason you know its not working? =)

Comment: The kernel being used is specific to the Nexus7 hardware so you'd at least need a new kernel to get it working and likely there might be some other issues that would need to be fixed if you did a port.

Comment: Noting that the installer now supports 32G Nexus 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

*I am currently using a Samsung **Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0)** Android tablet 'alongside' Ubuntu (SSH, tethering, etc.), but I instead chose the Google (ASUS) **Nexus 7** to actually test install of Ubuntu.  It being the 'reference platform'.*

My understanding (still limited) is that the 'Nexus 7 Installer' replaces Android, while using the Nexus 7 'stock' ROM and any other additional elements to run.

You may need to investigate some of the other more generic approaches (dual OS, replacement ROM, etc.).

---

You should also checkout: [LinuxonAndroid >> Working Devices](http://linuxonandroid.org/working-devices/)

Comment: *Update: currently installing (and testing) on **Nexus 7**.*

Comment: **Update 2:** *This is clearly a work in progress, and any effort to improve will (likely) be solely focused on this 'reference' hardware.*