# Can Ubuntu nexus 7 installer be ported to Asus Transformer TF700?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use the Ubuntu Nexus 7 Desktop Installer on other tablets?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207387/can-i-use-the-ubuntu-nexus-7-desktop-installer-on-other-tablets)

Is this something that would be possible?
Would be very nice if that would be possible, TF700 has full root and even NVflasher available for us :)